# Access denied on Apache subfolder

Tags: apache, apache2, debian

I have created an Apache2 server which is accessible from the Net. But when I added a subfolder which is: myserver/test
=> this address is not accessible (404 Not found error)

How can I fix this?

Comment: check the permissions on the folder

Comment: No, permissions are OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found the solution.
Indeed, i wanted to add a virtual host, so i've modified the apache2.conf file. And in the bottom of this file, i've commented an important line which is : `include available-sites`

Right now every thing is ok

Answer (score 1):

first of all, are you sure you created the new folder `test` in the correct place?
on Debian, apache2 is configured by default to have a SiteRoot (the *root* of your static websites) to live in `/var/www`. obviously, only files/directories that are within this directory will be served by apache.

your webserver is running as a system user (on Debian this is `www-data` by default). as such, the webserver may only access files that this user may access. chances are, that you have created the new folder with permissions that prevent the webserver to access any files (or the folder itself). to fix it use something like:

```
  chgrp -R /var/www/test
  chmod -R g+rX /var/www/test
```

Comment: i have checked the permissions before, it was working correctly, till i have decided to reboot the server !!!

Answer (score 0):

just check if you have read permission on the sub directory or folder with command `ls -la`
you can give read access permission on the sub folder

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/subfolder 
Or 
chmod -R 775 /var/www/subfolder
```

as per your folder structure